# How do I Count Milliseconds in Cocos2dx?

Tags: c++, time, cocos2d-x

Having some struggle showing milliseconds in Cocos2dx.  I would like to avoid having different code bases for different machines.

This works on 32bit iPhone/iPod platforms, but on 64 bit it always returns zero seconds and no time passes:

```
timeval time;
gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
unsigned long millisecs = (time.tv_sec * 1000) + (time.tv_usec / 1000);
return (float)millisecs;
```

This functions identically on 64bit iPhone/iPod platform AND 32bit, but is based on clock cycles, so if the user gets a text message or has programs open in the background, the time dilates:

```
clock_t t;
t = clock();
return 10000.0 * ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

This counts time accurately, but only in seconds (not milliseconds):

```
auto timeInMillis = std::time(nullptr);
```

The only way I've found to do it is to set a recurring update event & add the dt into a float (which appears to always be accurate), which is ok but not ideal.

Basically in update I have

```
timeElapsed += dt;
```

Which is ok, but it only works if there's an ongoing time counting update running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a discrepancy in 32 and 64 bit devices and how they report time.  The code snippet that works fine on 32 bit devices:

```
timeval time;
gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
unsigned long millisecs = (time.tv_sec * 1000) + (time.tv_usec / 1000);
```

will set "millisecs" to 0 on all 64 bit devices.  The only working solution I've found is to have a float value named "_millisecs", and on the first line of my update() function, I add dt to _millisecs.  This does not provide accurate reporting inside of a function, but it will at any time report precisely how much time has elapsed since update() was first scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

Hi use this to measure time start/stop in cocos2d-x. I use it in the cpp file. I get this snippet from https://code2relax.wordpress.com/tag/measure/ and works well.

```
typedef unsigned long long timestamp_t;

struct time_measure {
  timestamp_t start;
  timestamp_t stop;
  double result;
};

timestamp_t get_timestamp() {
  struct timeval now;
  gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
  return now.tv_usec + (timestamp_t)now.tv_sec * 1000000;
}

void update_time(struct time_measure *t) {
  t->result = (t->stop - t->start) / 1000000.0L;
  CCLOG("%f", t->result);
}
```

When I need to measure inside function:

```
time_measure tm;

tm.start = get_timestamp();
// long running task, download images
tm.stop = get_timestamp();
update_time(&tm);
```

You can move *time_measure tm as private property, typedef and function declarations* to .h file. To cpp *file function implementations* and you can measure time from any place in your cocos2d-x scene.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply!  This works great for me on 32bit iPhone and android, but when I call it on 64 bit iPad it always returns a zero, so none of the timers are running.

Comment: Hi I run it on iPhone6 and works. Can you check that you have some ( intensive work) between tm.start and tm.stop?  When they are too close iOS device is very fast and result may be zero. Also try to print values inside get_timestamp using  CCLOG("U time:%llu", now.tv_usec + (timestamp_t)now.tv_sec * 1000000); You will see numbers so must work.

Comment: Works fine for me on iPhone6 and my iPad Air, but my iPad mini 2, the gettimeofday(&time, NULL); always returns 0.  I've read about some weird issues with iPad 2 so maybe it's unique to that machine (or maybe I'm breaking something elsewhere in the code).  I'll do a HelloWorld build today to test your snippit & work backwards

Comment: Hi, so you have a problem with your device, not with "How do I Count Milliseconds in Cocos2dx?". Please close and up vote, if was useful.

Comment: There is no problem with my device, there is a difference in 64 and 32 bit architecture time reporting that I was not able to solve.